# Media queries not working in php files

Tags: php, css, media-queries

Hi in my php files media queries are not being read from my css, but if i save my php files as html files my media queries do work.

im using php so i can us the include function e.g.

is there a way to make my media queries still work in php files?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: http://79.170.44.126/rkhconsultants.co.uk/

Comment: I know am very late to this post, but this may help someone..
I got the same problem in my website, after checking everything i found i didnot add `<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">` in my `head` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you calling mediaqueries css? Mediaqueries are independents from the page extension.
I use mediaqueries in a php file without problems.
I call them in the head of my php file:
per example.:

```
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/mediaqueries.css" />
</head>
```

In the style.css are the general styles and is in the mediaqueries.css file where i apply my styles for any dispositive, for explample:

```
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 768px) 
and (max-width : 1024px) {
   /* specific CSS for IPad*/
}
```

Comment: thats what im using but its not working, heres my link http://79.170.44.126/rkhconsultants.co.uk/

Comment: actually this worked, must of had bad syntax in my css

Answer (score 0):

Media queries is a **CSS** feature and should not be in a PHP file, it should be in an **external CSS file** and should be included by a `<link>` tag.

like in:

```
<link href="http://server.info/jquery.socialist.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

If, for a specific reason, you have to dynamically generate your media queries, using PHP, keep including your PHP script on a `<link>` tag.

```
<link href="http://server.info/your_css_generated_with_php.php" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: they are in a css files check my page http://79.170.44.126/rkhconsultants.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

You have a media query that only looks for`320px to 480px`. But you are giving a width of `980px` to the .container. Obviously, it doesn't look right to me. You may want to re-visit your styles.

Comment: that was just a bad paste just making the background black for now to know that the query is working